# Reference paper for SDFormat (citation in bibliography)

Tags: gazebo-all-versions, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi there, my question is not related to Gazebo itself, so I am not sure that this is the right place to ask my question: how should I **cite** the SDFormat in the bibliography of a scientific article?
Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26246/reference-paper-for-sdformat-(citation-in-bibliography)/) by [Simone](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24349/simone/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 30 on 2020-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi! That's great that you want to cite SDF in your work. Your best bet would probably be to cite the SDF website: http://sdformat.org/. You could also cite specific pages like a certain page from the [documentation](http://sdformat.org/tutorials?) or [specification](http://sdformat.org/spec) tabs if you're referencing a specific function or feature. Other than that, we don't require any more specific citation than that. Let us know if you need more information than that!

---

Originally posted by [marya](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/38824/marya/) with karma: 16 on 2020-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0